# Connecting MYSQL database to with Ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to connect a local MYSQL database to my Ruby on Rails app but get a command prompt error.

I've installed the following gems:

```
gem 'mysql'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

My database.yml file is:

```
Development:
  adapter:  mysql
  host:     localhost
  Port:     3306
  database: betifydb
  username: root
  Password: Password
```

When I launch my rails server through the command prompt i get this error:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/upiWu.png

Thanks guys.

Comment: You forgot to paste your error here.

Comment: Could you paste the error? In the meanwhile make sure you had a look to the [**documentation**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Comment: Sorry guys edited the post with the error.

Comment: A MySQL API is not found error implies that maybe you don't have the MySQL server running on your dev machine.

Comment: you should ensure what on your localhost is runing MySQL process and it uses port 3306